# Base64.getEncoder() cannot resolve

Tags: java, android-studio, aes

Android studio почему-то не может разрешить этот метод.
Ниже представлен сам класс:

```
package com.example.chernovik;


import android.util.Base64;



import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;




public class AesCrypto {

    String key = "0123456789abcdef"; // 128 bit key
    String initVector = "abcdef9876543210"; // 16 bytes IV, it is recommended to use a different random IV for every message!

    private static String CIPHER_NAME = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
    private static int CIPHER_KEY_LEN = 16; //128 bits

    /**
     * Encrypt data using AES Cipher (CBC) with 128 bit key
     *
     * @param key  - key to use should be 16 bytes long (128 bits)
     * @param iv   - initialization vector
     * @param data - data to encrypt
     * @return encryptedData data in base64 encoding with iv attached at end after a :
     */
    public static String encrypt(String key, String iv, String data) {

        try {
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(fixKey(key).getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AesCrypto.CIPHER_NAME);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec);

            byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal((data.getBytes()));

            String encryptedDataInBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedData);
            String ivInBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(iv.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            return encryptedDataInBase64 + ":" + ivInBase64;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private static String fixKey(String key) {

        if (key.length() < AesCrypto.CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
            int numPad = AesCrypto.CIPHER_KEY_LEN - key.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < numPad; i++) {
                key += "0"; //0 pad to len 16 bytes
            }

            return key;

        }

        if (key.length() > AesCrypto.CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
            return key.substring(0, CIPHER_KEY_LEN); //truncate to 16 bytes
        }

        return key;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt data using AES Cipher (CBC) with 128 bit key
     *
     * @param key  - key to use should be 16 bytes long (128 bits)
     * @param data - encrypted data with iv at the end separate by :
     * @return decrypted data string
     */

    public static String decrypt(String key, String data) {

        try {
            String[] parts = data.split(":");

            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[1]));
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AesCrypto.CIPHER_NAME);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);

            byte[] decodedEncryptedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[0]);

            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(decodedEncryptedData);

            return new String(original);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы импортируете `android.util.Base64`, а использовать его пытаетесь как `java.util.Base64`. Замените `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedData)` на `Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT)`.